# overlaying a web template on a canvas animation

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have an animated canvas and i am trying to overlay a responsive web template on top of it, however the web template just sits at the bottom of the canvas and not on top of it. I have tried to change the absolute layout but that then removes the responsive aspect of the website.

I have also tried to add a zindex but again that didn't make any difference, any advice or nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

A link to the template is below

```
 http://www.redstardigitalmedia.co.uk/blue/index.html
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I modified your page using chrome developper tool, I've added to your canvas element:

```
    <canvas id="world" width="1600" height="779" style="
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;">
```

and to your page :

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix" style="
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;">
```

And it works fine (although the canvas animation fluency could be improved, do you use requestAnimationframe ?)